# How To Separate & Store Strings Into Variables From a CSV Line Using Python?

Tags: python, string, csv

how can I separate and store strings from a CSV line for example;

I have this string:

```
data = "product name, description, weight, shipping dest"
```

and I want to save into python variables like this:

```
a = "product name"
b = "description"
c = "weight"
d = "shipping dest"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If its a csv file you should use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. There are probably a ton of SO answers showing how to do this, so I wont repeat them.

Comment: Sorry, Its not accutaly a CSV file, just a string received from a barcode seperated by commas.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Use the string's split function:

```
data = "product name, description, weight, shipping dest"
a, b, c, d = data.split(', ')
```

Here's the Python 2.7 reference for it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

And here's the reference for Python 3:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Thank you! just what I was looking for , some type of delimiter in python.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. If it solves your problem, could you accept it as the answer please?